# To fill a dataframe column by values in another dataframe column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = 
  item  sale
0   7   10.0
1   4   10.0
2   6   10.0
3   5   10.0
4   5   10.0
5   6   10.0
6   4   10.0

df2 =
   item sale
0   1   7
1   2   6
2   3   5
3   4   4
4   5   3
```

I want to change the values of df1 sales column, taking the values from df2 sales column.

I use the code:

```
df1.loc[df1.item.isin(df2.item), ['sale']] = df2[['sale']]
```

And I get

```
df1 =
item    sale
0   7   10.0
1   4   6.0
2   6   10.0
3   5   4.0
4   5   3.0
5   6   10.0
6   4   NaN
```

The output I wanted was:

```
df1 =
  item  sale
0   7   10.0
1   4   4.0
2   6   10.0
3   5   3.0
4   5   3.0
5   6   10.0
6   4   4.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two dataframes are related by item number. So, set the item number as the index on both dataframes, run an [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) method on df1 with df2, and reset index

```
df1 = df1.set_index("item")
df1.update(df2.set_index("item"))
df1.reset_index()

    item    sale
0   7   10.0
1   4   4.0
2   6   10.0
3   5   3.0
4   5   3.0
5   6   10.0
6   4   4.0
```

Comment: Never used `df.update`. Learnt something new. Nice answer +1.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Any idea, what was wrong in my code.

Comment: alignment. Pandas will try to align on the indices and assign values based on the aligned indices. so if we look at ur ```df1.item.isin(df2.item), ['sale']``` , indices returned will be 1,3,4,6; however, the indices for df2 for the same values are 1,3,4, so it will pass the values at 1,3,4 to df1, which is not what we want, and since there is no 6 in df2, it returns a null value. that's why the first step is to get the items as indices, that way Pandas aligns it the way we want and from there, things should work out.